# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, statistics, moderation

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Hinduism breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  9          5
Users destroyed                                  81          0
Users deleted                                    27          0
Users contacted                                  13          0
User suspensions lifted early                     2          0
User banned from review                           2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           518      2,151
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               35        822
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         46        665
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               37        295
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               131        703
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              219      3,099
Tags merged                                       8          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          1
Tag synonyms created                              5          0
Revisions redacted                               11          0
Questions unprotected                             0          6
Questions reopened                               33         56
Questions protected                               9        101
Questions migrated                                4          1
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                               35        496
Questions closed                                413        411
Question flags handled⁴                         401        130
Posts unlocked                                    0          6
Posts undeleted                                  40         49
Posts locked                                      6        237
Posts deleted⁵                                  427      1,039
Posts bumped                                      0        276
Escalations to the CM team                        6          0
Comments undeleted                               70          0
Comments flagged                                 44      1,451
Comments deleted⁶                             2,950      4,924
Comment flags handled                         1,198        297
Answers flagged                                  87      1,983
Answer flags handled                          1,173        897
All comments on a post moved to chat             70          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks! Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy new year Shog9 :-)

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Thanks and wish you the same. Err, wrong account and wrong site. ;-)

Comment: @sarvabhouma hmm what? I know that Nog Shine is sockpuppet of Shog. But you are Sarvabhouma :P

Comment: Users destroyed -- what does this mean?

Comment: @Rickross accounts which get destroyed with the user's content  by mods or CMs. Usually downright spammers

Comment: Okay @AnkitSharma .....