# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Hinduism over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                   7          5
Users deleted                                      1          0
Users contacted                                   13          0
User suspensions lifted early                      1          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue             77        470
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                 9        432
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue          26        751
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                32        168
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                230        355
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               134      2,077
Tags merged                                        4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              2          0
Tag synonyms created                               2          0
Revisions redacted                                 4          0
Questions unprotected                              0          6
Questions reopened                                15         31
Questions protected                                0        121
Questions migrated                                 4          0
Questions merged                                   2          0
Questions flagged⁵                                13        390
Questions closed                                 306        284
Question flags handled⁵                          299        104
Posts unlocked                                     0          2
Posts undeleted                                   14         74
Posts locked                                       4         39
Posts deleted⁶                                   400        846
Posts bumped                                       0        194
Escalations to the Community Manager team          1          0
Comments undeleted                               124          0
Comments flagged                                  13      1,099
Comments deleted⁷                              3,563      4,021
Comment flags handled                            794        318
Bounties canceled                                  1          0
Answers flagged                                   14      1,156
Answer flags handled                             954        208
All comments on a post moved to chat              78          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1523/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Thanks for this statistics, we hope to do better in this new year. Btw Happy new year to you too :-)

Comment: What does this post mean by? Does this post indicate that the Moderators performance?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv: When Shog9 still worked for Stack Exchange, he had the habit of regularly posting these statistics on local Meta sites around the network so people could see how the various tasks that could be classified as "moderation" were being handled by each site. This helps people see how much of the moderation work - e.g. closing questions - is handled by regular community members (that have enough reputation to gain the necessary privileges) vs. how much is handled by moderators. It also lets people compare things like how many questions get closed to how many of those get reopened.